# PHP To Retrieve PostGIS Geography Types

Tags: php, postgresql, phpmyadmin, postgis

I have a PostGIS database with a geography column.  I'd like to be able to use PHP to SELECT the geography so then I could run another query using ST_Distance to get the distance between the points.  However, when I run

```
SELECT geog from locations;
```

I get a weird value of 6 instead of the HEX output (something like 0101000020E6100000C442AD69DEAD5740575BB1BFEC6E3D40 is what I'm expecting).  When I use the same query in phpPgAdmin I get the expected output, but not from my PHP script :(

I'd really appreciate any help :)

Thank you,

elshae

**EDIT**

```
$locations_result = @pg_query($DBConnect, "SELECT geog from locations;");

    if (!$locations_result) {
        echo "An error occurred upon getting data from the locations table.\n";
        exit;
    }
    $i = 0;
    while ($locations_arr = pg_fetch_row($locations_result)) {

        $locations['location'][$i] = $locations_arr[0];

                echo $locations['location'][$i];
        $i++;
    }
```

**EDIT2**
So now I am trying to select the geography right into the ST_Distance function so that it can just get the geography result directly, something like:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(geog_a, geog_b) FROM(SELECT geog AS geog_a FROM location WHERE id=123 UNION SELECT geog AS geog_b FROM location WHERE id=345);
```

But my SQL syntax is wrong and I have yet to figure out how I can get the result I'm aiming for.  The UNION is putting these values into one column, which is what I have already.  Instead I need something like:

```
geog_a |geog_b
----------------
hdsklgh|shfksh
```

Comment: How can you expect help with your PHP code if you don't post any?

Comment: Actually I seemed to have slipped on that one, posting now.  Thank you for pointing that out! :)

Comment: Have you tried `geog::geography`?

Comment: If you mean:
`SELECT geog::geography FROM locations;`
Then yes I just did and still got an output of 6 :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it the wkb-format you want?

```
select ST_AsWKB('geog') from locations
```

But why do you want to pull out the data first to do the distance-calculation?

/Nicklas

**Update**

Ok

I don't know why you don't get a proper result on your queries. I am too bad in php. I would guess that the result by some reason is pushed into some data type that is not the right. I mean from ST_AsText you should just get a string, nothing more strange than that.

But to get your distance you shouldn't pull out the points. You do a self join to do that. That is what you do all the time when using PostGIS and comparing different geometries in one single table.

Let's say the first geography has id=1 and the second has id=2 the query could be something like:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(a.the_geog, b.the_geog) as dist 
from locations a, locations b WHERE a.id=1 and b.id = 2;
```

If you want the distance to all points (or whatever it is) from point with id=1 you could write:

```
SELECT  ST_Distance(a.the_geog, b.the_geog) as dist
from locations a inner join locations b on a.id != b.id WHERE a.id=1;
```

and so on.

That will be very much more effective.

/Nicklas

Comment: what do you want to get. nothing you get seems unexpected.

Comment: Sorry about the last comment, this is what I was really going to post..
I just tried both:
`SELECT ST_AsBinary(geog) FROM locations;`
and 
`SELECT ST_AsText(geog) FROM locations;`

Comment: I'm still having the same problem I get the wrong output.  I did also try `ST_AsWKB` but it seems that PostGIS does not have that one and `ST_Binary` would be it's equivalent.

Comment: I guess what I want to get is the Geography object so that I could then enter it in the ST_Distance function.  The problem is that I am using PHP to talk to the database and PHP isn't keeping the geography result in a format understood by the ST_Distance function.  I pull the data first before doing the calculation because I need to get two geography results from on table based on their ID...

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will be using this:
`SELECT ST_Distance(a.the_geog, b.the_geog) as dist 
from locations a, locations b WHERE a.id=1 and b.id = 2;`
compared to the monstrosity I finally came up with :p
`SELECT ST_Distance(geog_a,geog_b) FROM(SELECT geog as geog_a FROM locations where id=3825) as pl, (SELECT geog as geog_b FROM locations where id=1488) as gl;`
I am really thankful for your kind help :)